# Itersection of $T_1$ spaces

Tags: general-topology

how to prove that if $(X,τ_1)$ and $(X,τ_2)$ are $T_1$-spaces, then $(X,τ_3)$ where $$τ_3=τ_1\capτ_2$$ is also $T_1$ space? I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do from the following characterization of $T_1$ space: a space $(X, \tau)$ is $T_1$ iff for any $x\in X$, the set $\{x\}$ is closed with respect to $\tau$.

Now if $x\in X$, then $\{x\}$ is closed with respect to the topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, that is $\{x\}$ is closed with respect to $\tau_3$. So $(X, \tau_3)$ is a $T_1$ space.